# 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, command-line, mysql-command-line-client

When I try logging into MySQL through command line to create a new user its "not recognized". It might have something to do with my "socket"? On MySQL workbench my socket just says "mysql" i dont know if i should change that? I have no clue about mysql. PLease help.

Comment: "not recognized" is NOT the same as "not allowing". not allowing is you connected, but don't have the rights to do something. not recognized means the mysql program itself can't be located (e.g. not installed, not in your path).

Comment: if it is on your machine you can just use mysql -u (USER) -p

Comment: @MarB sorry it says not recognized, ill change that now.

Comment: Please give the exact error in question. It helps get an answer.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond , it says "mysql" is not recognized specifically

Comment: You definitely need to install mysql

Comment: @miltoxbeyond Im positive i installed it at the beginning of the course maybe something didnt install correctly??? I have the workbench and everything

Comment: Are you running it in windows or linux or Mac

Comment: windows @MiltoxBeyond

Answer (score 0):

If the error you are getting is `'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` then you probably don't have mysql on the PATH. First, try closing your cmd window and open another one. After installing software, the PATH variable will be updated, but cmd windows don't update after they're opened.

Comment: What do you mean after installing software, is there something i need to install?

Comment: I opened a new cmd window and it still did not work.

Comment: Not every computer has mysql installed automatically. Is this a windows computer or linux computer? can you confirm that I got the error text exactly right, because small subtleties can make a big difference sometimes. It could be that MySQL workbench is showing you information about the database _server_, but your computer doesn't have a mysql client installed.

Comment: The error you put was exactly right. How do i make sure mysql is installed, i went through the whole process up until this put its giving my trouble...

Comment: I always google "install XYZ" and follow the links to install it. That's how all maintenance is done -- by google :). I don't think helping install mysql is in the scope of this question though.

Comment: I dont understand, what is XYZ? Also it says i need apache, I'm using the default WEBrick at the moment for this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You have to either run mysql from the add installation path or add the path of MySQL to your system path variable.

The simplest solution is to execute from the installation path, which is most likely c:\program files\mysql\bin out something similar

Comment: Is it the "MySQL server" folder i should go into? I found this.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin     the mysql.exe is in there

Comment: I just found a video on how to add it to my path

Comment: OKAY SORRY IT WORKED, now its just saying "access denied"

Comment: That is just a login issue.  Either username or password incorrect.  Try MySQL -u root -p

Answer (score 0):

With **"environment variables"**, search and click on **"Edit the system environment variables"**:

[image]

Then, click on **"Environment Variables..."**:

[image]

Then, set **"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin" (in my case)** to **"Path"** of either or both **"User variables"** or **"System variables"**:

[image]

Then, with **the command** below, open **MySQL Command-Line Client**:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Don't open **MySQL Command-Line Client** with **the command** below:

```
mysql
```

Because you will get this error below:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)